# Cast string representation to Json

Tags: c#, json

I have a string in this representation

```
{
    transaction_id = 120,
    transaction_shortname = 120. AUTO
}
```

It is not a Json representation i want to know if there is a simple way to transform it to Json representation like this:

```
 {
        "transaction_id": "120",
        "transaction_shortname": "120. AUTO"
 }
```

After that i can do the following to get a Transaction object:

```
        JObject j = JObject.Parse("{\"transaction_id\": \"120\",\"transaction_shortname\": \"120. AUTO\"}");
        transaction ttttt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<transaction>(j.ToString());
```

Comment: You can use something like `string outp = inp.Replace(@"transaction_", "\"transaction_")
   .Replace(" = ","\": \"")
   .Replace(","+ Environment.NewLine, "\"," + Environment.NewLine)
   .Replace(Environment.NewLine+"}", "\""+Environment.NewLine + "}");`

Comment: I can't do it and i can't do a loop on properties and construct the json for performance issues

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't be converted to JSON automatically, you need to parse the format you have manually. And I don't know any language which supports this syntax.

However, if you're absolutely sure there won't be some complex cases like quoted strings and "=" and "\"" in values, you can just apply regex:

```
Regex.Replace(
    source.Replace("\r\n", "\n"),
    @"(\n\s*)([^\n]*?)\s*=\s*([^\n]*?)([,\n])",
    "$1\"$2\": \"$3\"$4")
```

Answer (score 1):

The excerpt you've given qualifies as HJSON, and so can be parsed by any HJSON library.  https://hjson.org/

Comment: HJSON uses : in place of =

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response,

Lets say i have an object
object j ;
it's base is

```
{
    transaction_id = 120,
    transaction_shortname = 120. AUTO 
}
```

I ended by doing the following :

```
   transaction t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<transaction>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j));
```

Comment: No, this isn't correct at all.  Newtonsoft doesn't understand this example; although it handles unquoted property names and comments, it doesn't know what to do with the `120. AUTO` and gives a parse error on it.

Comment: When I make JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j) i get a correct Json string